# Failed to set Android sdk location in Android studio 3.0.1 on windows 8.1

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, windows-8.1, android-sdk-manager

[image]

Not able to set path for android sdk .Specific problem is that You can not able to click on textbox.

in fact in above image the all the buttons , checkbox and textbox are not clickable.

How to solve this problem please help me.I searched so much on internet but did'nt get any relevent answer for me.

Comment: Can you press edit?

Comment: yes! i did click on the edit but get no reponse.

Comment: Hey alexander.polomodev please help me .i have been stuck on this problem from so much time!